# A sequence 〈a_n〉 is defined recursively ,and find infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence $〈a_n〉$ is defined recursively by the equations

$a_0=a_1=1$

$n(n-1)a_n=(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}-(n-3)a_{n-2}$

find infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n=$ ?

Comment: To get multicharacter subscripts, use braces.  So a_{(n-1)} gives $a_{(n-1)}$ instead of a_(n-1) giving $a_(n-1)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find the first few terms of the series.

**Hint:** Prove the pattern.

> Show that $a_n = \frac{1}{n!} $.

Once you know what you're supposed to show, it's [straightforward induction](https://brilliant.org/wiki/induction-recurrence-relations/) to prove the sequence.

**Hint:** What is the [Maclaurin series](https://brilliant.org/wiki/maclaurin-series/?subtopic=applications-of-differentiation&chapter=taylor-series#maclaurin-series) for $e^x$?

> Hence conclude that $ \sum a_i = e$.